# Add a site column 'version' to every document library in site collection

Tags: version

I have a site columns 'version' and want to add it to every document library in site collection. I can add for specific doc lib but 'add from existing column' but how can i add under every doc lib.Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the column to already existing libraries, use powershell.

```
$list = $web.Lists["My existing list"]
$field = $web.Fields["MyVersionColumn"]
$list.Fields.Add($field)
```

If you want to add the column to every new document library, create one library, save it as template and upload it to the site. Then users can select your "Version library".

Answer (score 1):

Note that SharePoint has a built-in versioning feature which, when enabled for a particular document library, automatically adds a Version column that is tied to the feature. Manually adding your custom site column may cause problems, or at the very least, confusion, when that column isn't managed through SharePoint's versioning capabilities.

I recommend using the built-in versioning features, which can be accessed by going to
**Library Settings** > **Versioning Settings**
and setting "Create a version each time you edit an item in this list?" to `Yes`, rather than attempting to add a Version column directly to the library.

Answer (score 0):

A simple "no-code" solution would be to add a site column to the "Document" content type (do this at the root level of the site collection). This will update every CT in every existing doc lib, and also future doc libs...